# Multiple fields in one line

Tags: vala

Is there any way to declare two (or more) field in the same line?

When i try:

```
public class Test : Object{
    private int i,j;
    public static int main(string[] args){
        stdout.printf("test\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And compile with `valac Test.vala` I get this error:

```
Test.vala:2.2-2.8: error: syntax error, expected declaration
    private int i,j;
    ^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one needs a separate declaration. Sorry, lots of typing. Although, `private` is implied, so you don't strictly need it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope that vala team adds this feature in the future (I think multiple declarations fields in one line is a basic feature :s)

Comment: It's not likely.  It's too easy to accidentally expose API in a way that makes it impossible to remove without breaking API/ABI.  In some cases (when using structs instead of classes) even *adding* a field can be an API/ABI break.  When you're doing something that major, requiring a bit of extra typing can be a good thing.

Comment: Also, since Vala treats types differently from C, `int* x, y` would mean different things in C and Vala. It's confusing enough in C as it is, so best for Vala to avoid confusion.